# C++ Must take either zero or one argument

Tags: c++

```
 Matrix Matrix::operator* (int f,const Matrix &matrix)
{  Matrix M;
 for (int a= 1; a <= matrix.x; a++)
{
 for (int b = 1; b <= matrix.y; b++)
 {M.Mas[a][b] = f * matrix.Mas[a][b];
//  M.Mas[a][b]=Mas[a][b];}
}
return M;
}
```

**'Matrix Matrix::operator*(int, const Matrix&)' must take either zero or one argument**
Выдает ошибку при попытке компиляции с перегрузкой оператора *,  в чем проблема? Как мне использовать два аргумента?

Comment: `Matrix Matrix::operator* (int f,const Matrix &matrix)` => `Matrix operator* (const Matrix &matrix,int f)` Если вы точно предварительно так объявили. *Покажите предварительное объявление*

Answer (score 3):

Оператор, определенный в классе, принимает в качестве первого операнда сам объект класса. Так что то, что вы попытались определить - некий (невозможный) тернарный оператор `*`.

Чтобы определить бинарный оператор с первым операндом `int` - его надо определять **вне** класса:

```
Matrix operator* (int f,const Matrix &matrix) { ... }
```

Со вторым `int` и первым `const Matrix &matrix` - можно как свободный оператор

```
Matrix operator* (const Matrix &matrix, int f) { ... }
```

или в самом классе

```
Matrix operator* (int f) const { ... }
```

Comment: скорее все статик

Comment: @AlexGlebe По-моему, это будет усложнение, нет?

Comment: со статиком не получилось у меня, только `friend` пашет

Comment: Обьявил перегрузку оператора я в классе через friend,здесь показал прототип перегрузки,friend Matrix operator* (const Matrix &matrix,int f); . Вообще смотрел в учебике,там схожий пример с дробями "friend TDrob operator + (int y, const TDrob &x)
{ TDrob d;
d.a = y*x.b + x.a;
d.b = x.b;
return d;
} Там описывался он так и все по всей видимости должно было работать